# How to make the button animates in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

How to animate(toggle) the button it self when click?

I tried as below

```
<div id="app">

  <button class="btn" @click="show = !show">
    click
  </button> 

</div>

<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      show: true
    }
  }
});
</script>

<style>
.button { position:fixed; top:100px; left:100px; }
.button.active { left:0; }
</style>
```

I expect the output that when click the button,  button move to left:0 position. And another click, it move to left 100.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 4 in your app?

Answer (score 2):

Use [class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) to bind the `active` class when `show` is `true`. You should also use the `button` class instead of `btn` as that's what you have in your CSS.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    show: true
  }
})
```

```css
.button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  transition: left 0.2s; /* added this for fun */
}

.button.active {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button class="button" :class="{active: show}" @click="show = !show">
    click
  </button>
</div>
```